# How to locate data source for unbound control?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I've inherited some Access VBA code and there are controls on a form (such as a listbox named `lstOrderID`, mentioned below) which have no RowSource property set (an empty string). I look in the code and find statements like this in various places:

- `Forms!frm_Customer.lstOrderID = rstCust!OrderID ' set from a record set`
- `Forms!frm_Customer.lstOrderID.Requery`
- `Me.lstOrderID = Me.lstOrderID.ItemData(0) ' set to first item in self`

But nowhere in the code is lstOrderID.RowSource being set.

How can `Requery` be called on a listbox that has no RowSource?

How can a listbox be set to a single value (`rstCust!OrderID`) from a record set, unless this is a list of values (although the debugger shows an integer in `lstOrderID.Value`)?

Here is more code:

```
Dim rstCust As Recordset
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rstCust = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE CustID=" & ID & _
                "AND Datetaken =Date() " & _
                "AND VendorID='" & Forms!frm_Customer.cboVendorID & "'")

Forms!frm_Customer.lstOrderID = rstCust!OrderID

rstCust.Close
db.Close
```

Another section:

```
Dim rstCust As Recordset
Dim blStatus As Boolean
Dim strSql As String
Set db = CurrentDb      

strSql = "SELECT Orders.OrderID " & _
            "FROM Orders " & _
        "WHERE (((Orders.DateTaken)=#" & Date & "#) " & _
        "AND ((Orders.VendorID)='" & Forms!frm_Customer.cboVendorID & "') " & _
        "AND ((Orders.CustID)=" & ID & "));"

Set rstCust = db.OpenRecordset(strSql)
Forms!frm_Customer.lstOrderID = rstCust!OrderID

Forms!frm_Customer.lstOrderID.Requery
Forms!frm_Customer.lstOrderID = rstCust!OrderID

rstCust.Close
db.Close
```

Also this:

```
Me.lstOrderID.Requery
Me.lstOrderID = Me.lstOrderID.ItemData(0)
```

Comment: Seems to me there is a form - Frm_customer that has a an object, probably a list, that has the name lstorderID in it ? I guess i don't know what your asking.

Comment: That's right, form frm_Customer has listbox lstOrderID

Comment: Is there any options showing in the listbox at all? Or is it just simply a blank square?

Comment: Blank, even after the assignments made.

Comment: can you show the whole section of code? not really enough code to go on.

Comment: Added the code where the assignments happen.

Comment: What do you know about the original author?  Those `db.Close` statements suggest someone who doesn't understand Access basics very well.  You *can* `Requery` a list box which doesn't have a `RowSource` ... meaning Access won't throw a compile or run-time error ... but I don't see why that would be useful.  You can also set that list box's `Value`, but without a `RowSource` I don't see why a list box is useful --- you could use a text box instead.  OTOH, perhaps those choices make sense for reasons we can't see.  Can you share a copy of the database?

Comment: The client tells me the author was learning (from scratch) on the job.

Comment: Aha!  Well, on the bright side, it should require more billable hours to clean up the mess.  :-)